# How to parse array of objects of json with SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift

completely new to Swift here, so I have no idea how to even use print debugging, so thought I would ask here.

I am trying to parse a series of objects, each one of them in this format:

```swift
{
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Example Title",
      "targets": [
         {
            "name": "Example Name"
         },
         {
            "name": "Example Name"
         },
         {
            "name": "Example Name"
         },
         {
            "name": "Example Name"
         }
      ],
      "benefits": [
         {
            "name": "Example Benefit"
         },
         {
            "name": "Example Benefit"
         },
         {
            "name": "Example Benefit"
         }
      ],
      "steps": [
         {
            "name": "Example Step"
         },
         {
            "name": "Example Step"
         }
      ],
      "videoURL": "https://someurl.com"
   },
```

So I have a struct defined as such

```
struct Obj: Codable, Hashable {
    var id:Int
    var title:String
    var targets:[String]
    var benefits:[String]
    var steps:[String]
    var videoURL:String
}
```

And using

```swift
let objs:[Obj] = decode([Obj].self, from: "./Data/Objs.json")
```

Where decode is this function

```swift
func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type:T.Type, from filename:String) -> T {
    guard let json = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil) else {
        fatalError("Failed to locate \(filename) in app bundle.")
    }
    
    guard let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: json) else {
        fatalError("Failed to load \(filename) from app bundle.")
    }
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    guard let result = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: jsonData) else {
        fatalError("Failed to decode \(filename) from app bundle.")
    }
    
    return result
}
```

However when accessing the data in Objs, I get an error in the SwiftUI preview `objs.app may have crashed. Check ... for any crash logs in your application` which leads me to believe I am using JSONDecoder() incorrectly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't use `try?`, use `try` and print/log the error instead. `try?` should be used only when you understand the consequences of using it.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is how you are decoding inner content of the targets, steps and benifits.

Targets/Steps/Benifit contains array of object but in the `Codable` structure of yours, you have given it as a array of strings `[String]`. You need to correct that and Check.

Create one new structure:

```
 struct Name : Codable {
      var name : String
 }
```

Your final object will look like:

```
  struct Obj: Codable, Hashable {
          var id:Int
          var title:String
          var targets:[Name]
          var benefits:[Name]
          var steps:[Name]
          var videoURL:String
   }
```

**The key thing you should remember is that at the time of parsing nested object you will have to create another structure with codable conformance.**